Unable to create UserProfile object for User
I have a User model and a UserProfile model with a one-to-one relationship. I'm using a serializer to create users, and I want to automatically create a corresponding UserProfile object for each user upon creation.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the UserProfile object is not getting created when I create a new user. Despite setting up the UserProfile model with a OneToOneField relationship to the User model and specifying the related name as "userprofile", I keep getting an error stating that there is no related object.
Additionally, when I retrieve user data using the GET method with this serializer, the userprofile field shows as null, even though I expect it to contain the related UserProfile object.
Here's my UserSerializer:
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    profile_data = serializers.JSONField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = account_models.User
        fields = (
            "id", "username", "password", "email",
            "is_premium", "premium_time", "userprofile", "profile_data"
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
        }


    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile_data')
        image_path = profile_data.pop("image_path", None)
        password = validated_data.pop("password")

        user = account_models.User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        userprofile = profile_models.UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)

        if image_path:
            save_image(instance=userprofile, image_path=image_path)

        send_notification(user=user, action="CREATE_ACCOUNT")
        return user

And here's the relevant part of my UserProfile model:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    def image_path(self, filename):
        return f"Users/user_{self.user.id}/{filename}"

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userprofile")
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    biography = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=image_path)
    location = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    verify_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    verification_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Can you share the full error traceback in the question?

@SunderamDubey I don't receive any error traceback since the user is successfully created. However, despite the user creation being successful, the UserProfile object isn't created. As a result, when I retrieve user data using the GET method with this serializer, the userprofile field shows as null

To automatically create a UserProfile object when a new User is created, you can modify your create method like this:
def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile_data', {})
    password = validated_data.pop("password")

    user = account_models.User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    # Create or update the related UserProfile instance here
    userprofile, created = profile_models.UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user, defaults=profile_data)
    if not created:
        # If the UserProfile object already exists, update it with new data
        for key, value in profile_data.items():
            setattr(userprofile, key, value)
        userprofile.save()

    # ... handle image_path and send_notification as before

    return user

Here we used get_or_create()
to either retrieve the existing UserProfile object for the user or create a new one with the provided profile_data. And If the UserProfile object already exists, we updated it with the new data.
Additionally, you should remove the read_only=True argument from the userprofile field in your serializer, so:
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer()  # remove read_only=True
    # ...

This will ensure that the userprofile field is included when retrieving user data with the GET method.

I've tried implementing your solution, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue. I'm still facing the problem

@nima_sh Did you get any errors? Or just as before?
